# Functional equation $F(x+1) = x + F(x)$ and analytical expansion of Riemann zeta-function

Tags: functional-equations, riemann-zeta, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

I have found a solution for functional equation $F(x+1) = x + F(x) \tag1$

$F(x) = \frac{x(x-1)}{2}+C$, where $C$ - some constant

However, I have also tried to recursively expand equation $(1)$ at $0$:

$F(0) = -1 + F(-1) = -1 -2 + F(-2) = ... = -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 ... = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n} = -\zeta(-1)$

From that I conclude that $C = -\zeta(-1) = 1/12$

Can we say that $F(x) = \frac{x(x-1)}{2}+\frac{1}{12}$ is the only possible solution, or should we also append ", given zeta-function has analytical expansion to negative values"?

Comment: I less and less understand the downvoting frenzy on this site ! (score -3 before I upvoted it). The OP has a correctly stated question of his own !

Comment: Note that $ C $ is not necessarily constant. You can choose any periodic function $ C ( x ) $ with period $ 1 $, and let $ F ( x ) = \frac { x ( x - 1 ) } 2 + C ( x ) $, and you'll have a solution to the equation. If you want $ F $ to have further properties like continuity, differentiability or analyticity, you'll have to restrict your choice of $ C ( x ) $ to the suitable class of functions. But even then there could be choices other than the constant functions. For example, $ C ( x ) = \cos ( 2 \pi x ) $ gives an analytic solution.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari indeed! That's cool. Though I question more the validity of using zeta-function in this case. Because if it is valid reasoning, than we can't use just any $C(x)$, but only functional solutions to $C(x) = 1/12$ (otherwise $\zeta(-1)$ will be flawed).

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot conclude this. Each step of the way in your $\ldots$, you carry with you a copy of some $F(-n)$, which contains the same $C$ as $F(0)$ does on the other side of the equality sign. Taking the limit (which in this case is dubious in the first place, as the limit in the conventional sense doesn't exist) does not make that $C$ disappear, and indeed, any constant $C$ will actually work. A direct inspection will immediately show that no matter what $C$ is, the functional equation is still satisfied.

More explicitly, if we swap out $F$ for your expression, we get
$$
\frac{0(0-1)}{2} + C = -1 + \frac{-1(-1-1)}{2} + C\\
= -1-2 + \frac{-2(-2-1)}{2} + C\\
= -1-2-3 + \frac{-3(-3-1)}2 + C\\
\vdots\\
= -1-2-3-\cdots - n + \frac{-n(-n-1)}2 + C\\
\vdots
$$
The fact that you push the ${}+C$ further and further to the right as you go on doesn't mean that it disappears in the limit (even if we *were* allowed to take the limit). It's still there.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've clarified my question to point, which exactly equation I expand into infinite sum. I don't expand $x(x-1)/2+C$, but the original equation. But ok, so you say that we can't say that recursive $x+F(x)$ expands into "infinite Dirichlet sum", but it expands into "infinite Dirichlet sum plus some number"? And those can't be equal?

Comment: @danbst Regardless, you are careless in your limit-taking. Keeping the function without substituting, a general intermediate step of this process looks like
$$
F(0) = F(-n) - \sum_{i = 1}^n i
$$
and taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, you completely forget to take into account the $F(-n)$ term. I suspect that's because you in your notation are pushing it further and further to the right, and that looks like it might make it disappear. But you can't ignore it. Ultimately, the limit gives $F(0) = \infty - \infty$. Finally, please don't go down the "$\sum i = -\frac1{12}$" rabbit hole.

Comment: okay, I see now. So $$lim_{n->\infty} (F(-n) - \sum^n_{i=1} i) \neq -\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}$$
And we can't do that because both infinities are not commutative, even though they have recursive relation.